# How to store form info in a html5 sql database?

Tags: javascript, sql, html, client

I am creating a project that only uses client side languages. I want to get information from an html form and store it in a HTML5 Web SQL Database.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest the best way to do this. Should I some how store the form data in JavaScript vars and then pass those vars to the HTML5 SQL?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just posting what I mentioned in the comment above html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo Its very similar to what I wanted to achieve and helped me a lot

Answer (score -1):

webSQL is no longer a w3c supported standard. You should not do this, and no, this is not going to happen without a backend. Unless there's some magical thing i'm not aware of.

Comment: Thanks Flavor - yes I know its no longer supported and I don't like doing it, but due to the conditions of my project I have to :( (Its a PhoneGap project that packages a bunch of JS and HTML files and runs them as an 'app' on smart phones.

Comment: Hi all,

I found this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

Its similar to what I want to do

Comment: -1 this is a bad answer. Even though Indexeddb is the standard, every browser's implementation is different, and some still has major issues. WebSQL is absolutely critical in filling that gap. http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/12/Issues-with-IndexedDB-and-Chrome http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/25/IndexedDB-on-iOS-8-Broken-Bad